# How to get 304 from jQuery Ajax instead of 200?

Tags: jquery

My services returns a `304` but jQuery Ajax seems to convert it to a `200 OK`result.

This is my request:

```
$.ajax({    
    url: '/api/items',    
    type: 'GET',    
    dataType: 'json',    
    contentType: 'application/json',    
    ifModified:true,    
    cache: false,    
    statusCode: {    
        304: function() {    
            alert("not modified"); // does not fire
        }    
    },    

    complete: function (xhr, status) {    
        console.log(xhr.status); // 200 
        }    
    }    
});
```

With Fiddler I can see that the service returns `304` correctly.

Why does jQuery convert it to a `200`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if jQuery.ajax() request header Status is "304 Not Modified"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173656/how-to-check-if-jquery-ajax-request-header-status-is-304-not-modified)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You want to distinguish between them, use `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` event and read it from `jqXHR.status`

or access jqXHR other way:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax(
    ...     
    statusCode: {    
        200: function() {    
            if(304 == jqxhr.status)
                alert("not modified"); // does not fire
        }    
    },    
)
```

[Proper way to handle 304 not modified in jQuery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215181/proper-way-to-handle-304-not-modified-in-jquery-ajax)

***edit***

additional `ajax()` setting:

```
ifModified:true, // Lets respond `304:notmodified`
```

but it breaks data reponse:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-fix-browser-cache-and-notmodified-respond-for-json-jquery-ajax-ifmodified-true-break-on-data-respond

but You've used it and it still works differently :-/

Comment: which version of jQuery and which browser?

Comment: 1.7.2 / Chrome latest version / Firefox latest version

Comment: thanks - my main fault was that I hit refresh inside the browser instead of re-issuing the request.